# Should we have events in Pin 13?

Tags: discussion, chat

**Hi everybody! I'm the owner of the chatroom [Pin 13 (formerly *Arduino*)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8489/pin-13).** It was automatically assigned to me after my record of high activity on the chat room. Anyway, there is a option to add new *events* that show up.

[image: Schedule new eent]

I don't *have* to schedule a event, but this is our main chat room and I think it would be cool to do something. Additionally, the chat wouldn't be any different except a few notices to remind people about the event. Everyone can chat about normal topics, if they choose. It should last at least 24 hours for different timezones.

**Should we have anything on our chat room?** If so, what should we do? Please include a title for it and if it should be a regular occurrence.

Comment: Pin 13 doesn't support external interrupt events.

Comment: We should call our events vectors, after the interrupt vectors on the AVR CPU

Answer (score 2):

During the last iteration, we had a weekly meetup lasting half an hour every week for about 2 to 3 weeks in which there were 5-10 people participating. It usually went on for almost an hour however. That was, in my opinion quite successful, and I think we could try something similar.

> Weekly Meetup

The discussion can be kept open and spanning a range of topics. *It does help* if a single person takes the lead, and develops at least some sort of list of topics to discuss, and prevents the discussion from getting fixated on a single issue. It is likely that if we end up discussing a single *specific* issue for 30 minutes then, it would be better suited to a meta post than a chat discussion.

The event could be called `Setup() && Chat()`

Comment: Could you recommend a name and a when to do it (Sunday, etc.) please?

Comment: @Annonomous The time needs to be discussed and decided collectively by the people interested in participating. My suggestion won't help if no one is available at that time.

Comment: Or `void setup() { chat(); }`

Answer (score 1):

### Something that I thought of:

> Site Improvement Day

Anyone anytime can improve the site, but we should focus that day on how we can make it better. Be it retagging, cleaning up comments, or even just asking some new questions if the site suffers inactivity, let's get working!

This could be a bi-weekly or monthly event. People can always do things like above, but we can use the room to chart our progress and maintain our site, as well as review the healthiness of the site.

Comment: Just to clarify, by "bi-weekly" you mean every 2 weeks, right? In some places, it can mean twice a week.

Comment: @Peter Yes, two weeks (~2 per month) not every 3.5 days...